# Python Error email.mime has no attribute 'MIMEMultipart'

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am writing a project to use a Raspberry Pi 3 to send an email through Gmail. The project works great on my laptop but when I try to run the code on the Raspberry Pi the following error keeps getting reported:

```
email.mime has no attribute 'MIMEMultipart'
```

I have tried to re-install the email package using pip-install as suggested elsewhere, but it has not fixed the issue.  I am especially perplexed as this currently works on my laptop, but will not work on the Raspberry Pi 3.

My code is below:

```
import smtplib
import mimetypes
import email
import email.mime.application

FROM = "Sender's address" #This has been removed from this post, but normally contains sender's address
TO = "recipient's address" #This has been removed from this post, but normally contains recipient's address

msg = email.mime.Multipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Greetings'
msg['From'] = FROM
msg['To'] = TO


body = email.mime.Text.MIMEText("""hi""")
msg.attach(body)


filename= "path+filename" #e.g.(C:/Users/Pictures/pic.jpg)
fp=open(filename,'rb')
att = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype="jpg")
fp.close()
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
msg.attach(att)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
s.starttls()
s.login('FROM','PASSWORD') #password is actually entered here in my real code, it has been removed from this post
s.sendmail('FROM',['TO'], 
msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out by myself. Adding an import statement to the top of my code fixed the problem:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be an installation problem.
Check in your python installation folder whether there is a file multipart.py in Lib/email/mime folder.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, there is a multipart.py file.